# Android Bluetooth - Connection monitor thinks connection is dead when it isn't

Tags: android, bluetooth, rfcomm

With the newest version of our software, I have some code to detect if there is no data being transferred from a Bluetooth connection. However, with our newest version of our software, some users are reporting that this code is being triggered even though the connection is fine. I haven't made any changes to this code ever since. I wonder if it is something different with the Android 12 Bluetooth stack that is causing something with this.

Note that I am unable to replicate this issue from my end, so this is apparently something that will be difficult to debug.

Here is my code:

```
//My connection monitor
public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (numBytes == 0) {
            watchdogTimer++;
            if (watchdogTimer == 10) {
                dataTimeout = true;
                eventHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_CONN_TIMEOUT, 0, -1, "Connection Dead?").sendToTarget();
                watchdogTimer = 0;
            }
        } else {
            watchdogTimer = 0;
            dataTimeout = false;
        }
        connectionMonitor.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};


//My byte reading code
public void run() {
    byte j;
    int lastone = 0;

    while (isRunning) {
        try {
            if (inStream != null && btSocket.isConnected()) {
                j = (byte) inStream.read();
                if (j == -1)
                    continue;

                if ((j == 0xA) && (lastone == 0xD)) {
                    //check for buffer overrun
                    if (readBytes.position() == PACKET_SIZE - 1) {
                        readBytes.put(j);
                        numBytes++;
                        dataReset = false;

                        if (dataTimeout) {
                            dataTimeout = false;
                            connectionMonitor.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                            connectionMonitor.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
                        }
                    } else {
                        readBytes.clear();
                        numBytes = 0;
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (readBytes.position() == PACKET_SIZE) {
                        numSamples++;
                        if (bSendData) {

                            parseBytes(readBytes.array(), 0);

                            if (bWrite) {
                                write(readBytes.array());
                            }
                        }
                        if (dataTimeout) {
                            dataTimeout = false;
                            connectionMonitor.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                            connectionMonitor.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
                        }
                    }
                    readBytes.clear();
                    numBytes = 0;
                    continue;
                }
                lastone = j;
                if (readBytes.position() < PACKET_SIZE) {
                    dataTimeout = false;
                    readBytes.put(j);
                    numBytes++;
                    if (dataTimeout) {
                        dataTimeout = false;
                        connectionMonitor.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                        connectionMonitor.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
                    }
                } else {
                    readBytes.clear();
                    numBytes = 0;
                    //numSamples = 0;
                }
            } else {
                throw new IOException("No Bluetooth Stream!");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (isRunning && watchdogTimer == 0) {
                isRunning = false;
                Log.e("Bluetooth", e.getMessage());

            } else {
                Log.e("ConnectedThread", "Interrupted");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this? I would like a way to know if there is no data coming through but the tablet is still connected to the device, for I can display a warning message. Apparently some users are reporting they are randomly getting the message when they shouldn't be with our latest version of our software.